# Optimization in JPARepository/Hibernate Entity Retrieval

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'd like to inquire if the JPARepository/Hibernate implementation incorporates any optimization when retrieving the same entity ID multiple times during an API request call.

Furthermore, are there any distinctions in behavior if the entity was created and subsequently accessed multiple times?

I'm raising this question due to its critical relevance in our design considerations. If there is a substantial performance impact when retrieving the same entity multiple times within the JPA repository, it may necessitate sharing JPA entities across various business layer interactions.